# Aligning D3 Area Chart X-Axis Ticks correctly

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, d3

I am building an area chart using the D3 Library, and I used their [area chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/area-chart) example to help me construct it. However, I am not using dates as along the x-axis, instead I am using Strings, so I tried using their [bar chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/bar-chart) example to help me handle the xAxis and its values.

Due to this, though, my x axis tick marks are "centered" between two value points, rather than being left aligned (see image below).

[image: Sample Area Chart]

When I tried using the area chart example to construct the xAxis, I was not seeing any area being filled or any data points along the xAxis.

How can I move the tick marks to be aligned directly on the data point rather than centered between two different data points?

Here is what my code looks like when constructing the graph":

```
    sampleAreaData = [
        {"month": "Jun. 2018", "value": "2"},
        {"month": "Jul. 2018", "value": "12"},
        {"month": "Aug. 2018", "value": "33"},
        {"month": "Sept. 2018", "value": "100"},
        {"month": "Oct. 2018", "value": "150"},
        {"month": "Nov. 2018", "value": "368"},
        {"month": "Dec. 2018", "value": "404"},
        {"month": "Jan. 2019", "value": "482"},
        {"month": "Feb. 2019", "value": "559"},
    ]

    initializeSampleAreaGraph() {
        // Variables
        const svg = d3.select(this.template.querySelector('svg.sampleAreaGraph'));
        const width = this.svgSampleAreaWidth;
        const height = this.svgSampleAreaHeight;
        const margin = ({top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30});
        const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(this.sampleAreaData.map(d => d.month))
            .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(this.sampleAreaData, d => d.value)]).nice()
            .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);
        const xAxis = g => g
            .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));
        const yAxis = g => g
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
            .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                .text(this.sampleAreaData.month));
        const area = d3.area()
            .x(d => x(d.month))
            .y0(y(0))
            .y1(d => y(d.value));

        // SVG Construction
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .datum(this.sampleAreaData)
            .attr("d", area)
        svg.append("g")
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(yAxis);
        return svg.node();
    }
```

Comment: Because this relates to the D3 library, this will categorize as Off-topic for SFSE. You may like to get help either on Stackoverflow or any other forum where D3 topics are discussed.

Comment: @JayantDas thanks, I have also asked on Stack Overflow. I posted here as well because using their example directly did not work in Salesforce.